# Using mt.exe with MSBuild on Azure DevOps. MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: mt.exe unexpectedly not a rooted path

Tags: c++, azure-devops, msbuild

I want to assemble something using mt.exe on Azure DevOps. Hence, I created an MSBuild task for my pipeline, which basically looks like this:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.csproj'
```

I have a mytool.csproj, which just defined the MT task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="16.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />
  <Target Name="Build">
        <MT Sources="mytool.manifest" OutputResourceManifests="mytool.exe"></MT>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

However, when this pipeline runs I get the error:

```
Build:
  mt.exe /outputresource:"mytool.exe" /manifest mytool.manifest
##[error]mytool.csproj(7,9): Error MSB4018: The "MT" task failed unexpectedly.
Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: mt.exe unexpectedly not a rooted path
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInternalError(String message, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInternalRooted(String value)
   at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.TrackerExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
   at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.VCToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

What does `mt.exe unexpectedly not a rooted path` mean? I checked with `where mt.exe` that
the mt.exe is available, which is confirmed by the result:

```
Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64
```

How can I successfully run mt.exe on Azure DevOps? I would also be open to any other way (e.g. not using MSBuild) if that would be an option.

Comment: If you can make it work on local, I suggest you set up a [self-host agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) based on the machine, so that you will have the same environment. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I does work on locale. But I do not want a self-hosted agent.

Comment: The error indicates that internal to the `MT` task, the mt.exe executable can not be found. What are you using for the agent host? Is "Visual Studio" or "Build Tools for Visual Studio" installed on the agent host? Has the C++ workload been included in the installation?

Comment: @JonathanDodds As shown above I use windows-latest. The stuff which is available there is officially documented (https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md). From my understanding it has all that dependencies installed

Comment: Yes, that image has the required components.

Comment: Did you create your project file by hand? .csproj is a C# project. A C++ project uses the .vcxproj extension. My guess is that the project is incomplete and is missing parts of the C++ support.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Yes, I did. I am building a Java (Spring Boot) app using GraalVM and AOT. I only need this because I want to link my resulting.exe with UAC as my app requires admin rights. However, I don't think anything is missing as running MSBuild.exe works on my local machine without issues

Comment: As a test, create a new C++ project in Visual Studio, and build the C++ project in Azure DevOps with the 'windows-latest' VM image. There are a set of C++ only MSBuild tasks. In addition to `MT`, the C++ tasks include `CL` and `Link`. If a 'standard' generated project does or doesn't fail to locate `Cl` or `Link`, that will help point to where the issue may be,

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to define path info for `sources` and / or`OutputResourceManifests` here:

```
<MT Sources="mytool.manifest" OutputResourceManifests="mytool.exe">
```

Paths can be used when calling mt.exe from the command line. This could be an alternative, in stead of leaving it to msbuild, running mt.exe as script task.